# EventAggregator with MultiThreads

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, events

I am having a little problem with the IEventAggregator, let me explain

```
public class doSomething
{
    public doSomething()
    {
        Action<AddEvent> GetAddSolution = s => this.Add(s.a, s.b);
        IEventAggregator.GetEvent<AddEvent>().Subscribe(GetAddSolution);
    }

    public void Add(int a, int b)
    {
        IEventAggregator.GetEvent<AddSolutionEvent>().Publish(new AddSolutionEventArgs(a + b));
    }
}
```

Let above be a Demo service, in my case it is a long running one, now if i have multiple threads calling Add(a,b) using the EventAggrigator, the last thread which published request gets all the responses

how do i return response to the thread which published the request event.

Please Provide Guidance.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer my self, its simple, using event Filters in [eventaggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx). the filter delegate filters the events.